# allow ob_get_contents and to grab warnings but not display them in front end

Tags: php, error-reporting, ob-get-contents

I have a script developed in PHP7.2 running on a CentOS machine and I've been struggling to get **ob_get_contents** to work.

In the php.ini file, I have set `display_errors to Off` and error_reporting to this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Here's the code that gets executed:

```
    ob_start();
    $result = $db->query($query); //This executes a query
    $report_error = ob_get_contents();
    if (!$result)
                {
                    log_error("Query Failed: ".$report_error);
                    return false;
                }

   ob_end_flush();
   ob_start();
```

**Setting display errors to On works** but I don't want to display errors in the front end to the user, that's not something we would want in production so not sure if there's another setting in the php.ini file I need to change to capture warnings but not show them in the frontend?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `display_errors = On` and then selectively report errors when you are buffering for the errors using `error_reporting()`.

At the start of your application you want `error_reporting(0)`.

Also, don't *flush* the buffer, that sends the output to the browser.  You want to *clean* the buffer with `ob_end_clean()`.

Or *get* and *clean* in one:

```
ob_start();
error_reporting('E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE');  //report errors
$result = $db->query($query);
$report_error = ob_get_clean();
error_reporting(0);                    //report NO errors
if (!$result)
            {
                log_error("Query Failed: ".$report_error);
                return false;
            }
```

However, that database class probably implements a way to retrieve errors without having to go through this.

Comment: So you're suggesting to keep display_errors = On and use ob_get_clean()? If I do this it will still display some warnings in the front end correct?

Comment: You have to have them = on to output, then you are capturing that output in a variable and deleting the output.

Comment: I added an edit that works better.

Comment: Mark accepted if it solved your issue please.